# How to Click Link by URL in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework, robotframework-ide

In the [Selenium2 Robot Framework documentation][1], the guide to Click Link is:

> Clicks a link identified by locator. Key attributes for links are *id*,
>   *name*, *href* and link text. See *introduction* for details about locating
>   elements.

I have tried different ways to insert the URL using the *href* tag but I still could not get it work. May I have an example on doing this please? I could not use link text as I have multiple links with the same text (unfortunately named "Create") and they do not have any element id for me to reference.

I got this error:

```
ValueError: Element locator with prefix 'href' is not supported
```

Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    [Documentation]    Try to login
    Open Browser    {my login page by i cant post more than 2 links here. it's working fine here}    CHROME
    Input Text    //*[@id="rightColum"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input    username
    Input Password    //*[@id="rightColum"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input    password
    Click Button    //*[@id="Login2"]
    Click Link    href=https://test/enquire.aspx
```

Comment: Could you add the code you tried?

Answer (score 4):

The following should both work fine:

```
Click Link       href=http://link.com

Click Link       xpath=//a[@href="http://link.com"]
```

But if there is an = sign in your link, the first option will not work. You should add `default=` in front of `href=` to fix that.

Comment: Hi Bas, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried href, but i'm getting the following error: "ValueError: Element locator with prefix 'href' is not supported"

Comment: I tired the 2nd option, but the strange thing is that it returns the following error: "ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//a[@href="https://test/enquire.aspx"]' did not match any elements". But when I search for the url in View Source, I can see the url.

Comment: Dear @Jamie, `Click Link    href=test/enquire.aspx` ? (I see you added https, which does not make much sense I believe)

Answer (score 2):

This is what the document says, 
http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Click%20Link

You can use id, name, href and link text. Now I am not sure how exactly your html code looks but you can use any of the following methods

```
Click Link | id=my_element
Click Link | name=my_element
Click Link | default=page?a=b
Click Link | link=My Link
```

If nothing works, you can form an Xpath, CSS identifier and use **Click Element**

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can use this code.

```
*** Variable ***
   ${profile}          https://web.facebook.com/xxx
*** Keywords ***
Click Profile
   [Arguments]        ${xpath}
   Click Element      ${xpath}
*** Test Cases ***
   Go To           ${profile}
```

Hope to help.

Answer (score -1):

Create Hyperlink for URL in Robot Framework

```
** settings **

Library  Builtin

** Keywords **

To create Hyper Link
    Log  <a href="http://robotframework.org/">ROBOT</a>  HTML

** Test case **
Verify to create hyper for URL in robotframework
     To create Hyper Link
```

1) This will Create the Hyper link With **Robot** in Log.html File

Answer (score -1):

In my case as well the **Click Link** , **Click Element** was not working.

So tried the below code and it worked.

**Note :**

This code makes use of the library **ImageHorizonLibrary** along with **SeleniumLibrary**

```
Scroll Element Into View    xpath=//tbody/tr/td[1]/a[@class='searchLink']
Wait Until Element Is Enabled   xpath=//tbody/tr/td[1]/a[@class='searchLink']
Set Focus To Element    xpath=//tbody/tr/td[1]/a[@class='searchLink']
ImageHorizonLibrary.Press Combination   Key.Enter
```